# Using SQL Server Geography in C# entities without referencing Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5

I'm looking at using the new *Geography* types in Entity Framework 5 and 6 for my next project - see this tutorial link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj250903.aspx

I've created a *MyProject.Entities* Visual Studio library project containing my entity models.  The problem that I foresee is that I would need to reference Entity Framework 5+ in the *MyProject.Entities* project in order to use the `DbGeography` type that corresponds to the `geography` column in my SQL Server database when mapping this using Entity Framework (or at least that appears to be the case based on the instructions in the tutorial link above). I'd prefer not to directly reference the Entity Framework in my *MyProject.Entities* project since I'm planning to share this library across several project which may be using different versions of Entity Framework. In terms of style, I'd also like to keep the *MyProject.Entities* project as simple and clean as possible - coupling my entities project to the Entity Framework seems ugly by this criteria.

Here is a simplified example of one of my models:

```
namespace MyProject.Entities
{
    public class PointOfInterest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DbGeography Geo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else had this concern? If so, how did you get around it?

EDIT: I thought of a good way to articulate my concern. The new OWIN identity model provides interfaces like `IUser` so that developers can write their own implementations without referencing the Entity Framework directly, e.g. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Aspnet-Identiy-Core-7475a961. Unfortunately `DbGeography` doesn't seem to implement such an interface http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Spatial/DbGeography.cs so I'm stuck referencing the Entity Framework.

Comment: Maybe just use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx instead

Comment: Thank you ErikEJ, that looks very promising. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can just use

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx

Comment: Oh boo. I was confident this was the answer. But after mapping the entity to my DataContext I got this error: _error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:No mapping specified for properties PointOfInterest.Geo in Set PointsOfInterests._. The `Geo` property is of type `SqlGeography` and matches the database column name. I looked it up and it appears that Linq to SQL simply doesn't support `SQLGeography` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2846053/201648. There is an a SQL Server UDF implementation to solve the problem on the same thread - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2968633/201648

Comment: If you must acssociate your class with EF, you must use DbGeography

Comment: Thank you ErikEJ. Will mark as the answer on the basis of the above comment.